# what is the difference between rich:column and rich:columns

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, richfaces

Can anyone tell me the difference between `rich:column` and `rich:columns`?

Comment: I'd guess that rich:columns is a container that contains multiple rich:column elements

Answer (score 7):

You are using `rich:columns` when you want to create columns **dynamically**

Eg:

```xml
<rich:columns value="#{dataTableScrollerBean.columns}" var="columns" index="ind">

    <f:facet name="header">    
        <h:outputText value="#{columns.header}" />    
    </f:facet>

    <h:outputText value="#{model[ind].model} " />

</rich:columns>
```

while you're using `rich:column` when you simply have a column in a `rich:dataTable`

```xml
<rich:column>

    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Price" />
    </f:facet>

    <h:outputText value="Price" />

</rich:column>
```

Details [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_columns.html)

Comment: but what does value="#{model[ind].model}  exactly mean?

Comment: and how is value="#{columns.header}" and #{model[ind].model} declared in the bean?

Comment: @mmenus Columns in the bean can be a list of column objects, where column object can have any data you want: header, etc. `#{model[ind].model}` it's just an example of putting random data in an outputText. you can put `value="hello"` if it's too much too understand.